# Call a function from another file in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, function

I look on another questions, but cant really solve my problem. Im trying to call a function to open a modal with reactJS, but the call button is in one page and the modal files are in another to be reused if necessary, but when i click in it, its return a not a fuction error; Here is my code.

This is the button. The openModal is not working

```
<TableCell>
   <DbButton
   onClick={(e) => openModal(event.id)}
   >{<FormattedMessage id='delete' />}</DbButton>
</TableCell>
```

This is the modal in another file

```
const openModal = (eventId) => {
    setOpen(true)
    setEventId(eventId)
  }

  return (
    <Panel border={false}>
      <TableEventsComponent
        data={dataList}
        goTo={goTo}
        onChangePage={onChangePage}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={onChangeRowsPerPage}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        page={page}
        deleting={deleting}
      ></TableEventsComponent>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{<FormattedMessage id='alert-title' />}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            {<FormattedMessage id='alert-body' />}
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button 
            onClick={handleClose} 
            color="primary">
            {<FormattedMessage id='cancel' />}
          </Button>
          <Button  
            onClick={handleConfirm} 
            color="primary" 
            autoFocus>
            {<FormattedMessage id='confirm' />}
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </Panel>
  )
```

Any advice?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it will be hard for someone to help you.

Comment: use `export default openModal` and import it in your file.

Comment: In this line `onClick={(e) => openModal(event.id)}` you declaring param as `e` but using `event` variable :/

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete way to show the code. lankovova get this right, but i do a little more. Gonna answer with the correct way that works for me. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this project is abstracting most of the components, to be reusable and easier to do maintenance. The father index where the modal construction and the logic handles things had a events listener to receive the props passed by, and the son index where the page shows to the user and had the delete button just passa the props to call the function to do the job.

So, on the TableEventsComponent that i put on my second block of code on the question, i put a

```
openModal={openModal}
```

And, on the page i got the button, i had

```
const TableEventsComponent = ({
  openModal,
  ...
})
```

Thats it, i just not communicating the way it should be.